# Sencha JS Event Handlers Pointing to static function

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following code where I am wiring up a buttons click handler to an anonymous function. I would like to migrate the code to use a static function.

Current Code:

```
[ grid, { xtype: 'splitter' },
            { title: 'Person Details', bodyPadding: 5, flex: 2,
                    items: 
                    [
                        { itemId: 'txtName', fieldLabel: 'Name:', xtype: 'textfield'}, 
                        { itemId: 'txtAge', fieldLabel: 'Age', xtype: 'textfield'},
                        { itemId: 'btnShow', xtype: 'button', height: '60', width: '20%', align: 'right', text: 'Show Data', handler: function (){ btnTest_Click(); }}
                    ] 
            }       
        ]
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
handler: btnTest_Click()

function btnTest_Click()
{
  alert('Test');
}
```

I hope this makes sense. I come from a .NET programming background to give you some insight into why I do things the way do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handler expects a reference to a function. In the second part of the code you're executing the fucntion and passing the result to the handler.

`handler: btnTest_Click`

As a side note, you should probably avoid using global functions, Ext gives you better ways to structure your application.

Comment: Evan could you provide some examples on the Ext perfected structure for me?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there is no such thing as a `static` function, you can however mimic the behavior like this:

```
var count = (function(){
  var c = 0;
  return function(){
    return c++;
  }
})();
console.log(count()); console.log(count()); console.log(count());
```

Also, in JavaScript `function` names are really variables that execute with `()`, therefore

```
handler: function (){ btnTest_Click(); }}
```

and

```
handler: btnTestClick
```

would do the same thing.

An Anonymous `function` works like a `function` name.